# Union from two different entities but same viewmodel class

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have 2 different entities: EntityA and EntityB.

All fields are Strings.

I have a common ViewModel class: MyViewModel.

I have 2 queries:

```
var query1 = from a in EntityA select new MyViewModel { field1=a.somefield1, field2= a.somefield2 };

var query2 = from a in EntityB select new MyViewModel { field1=a.somefield3, field2="String Constant" };
```

EntityA and EntityB are different but my 2 queries gives us the same result: An IQueryable of MyViewModel.

So i am trying to make an union:

```
var query3 = query1.Union(query2);
```

I get this error:

> "Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides
> have different store types".

This is because EF does not put the same datatype for my string constant and a.somefield2. somefield2 is a varchar(100), but "String Constant" is a string and i don't know how EF translate it.

Thanks

The dotnet version is .Net5 and i am using Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.SqlServer 5.0.10

Comment: Linq to SQL, EF and EF Core are different technologies with different capabilities. Please specify the EF Core version in order to see if what you are asking is possible. Also the error says "matching columns on both sides have different store types" - not sure what that means, if they can be select into one and the same view model member, is the real case same as shown? what is type of the members and the corresponding entity property db columns?

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce - same EFC version, int and string properties, it works. So probably is something related to decimal and/or DateTime, try commenting out these properties one by one until it start working.

Comment: Okay i have understood the problem: This is a datatype issue: In one query, i am returning an Int value. But in the second query, i am doing a calculation between 2 int values. And the result is not int. I don't what it is. Is there a way to force the database datatype in the viewmodel class ? Thanks

Comment: Make the view model type match the one which both are convertible to? What is the type of the calculation? long? decimal? casts seem to work, at least for SqlServer.

Comment: My ViewModel contains datatypes (Int32 for this field). But there are no annotation for database datatype

Comment: I mean, inside the Select with the problematic field, can't you say `new ViewModel { intField = (int)tableOrView.nonIntFieldOrCalc, ...}`?

Comment: Thanks but there is multiple sizes for int in database. How can i specify which one ? And for strings, how can i cast to varchar(100) vs varchar(200) for example ? Thanks

Comment: First time hearing about different sizes of ints. Normally you have single Clr to Db integer type mapping - byte, short, int, long - all they have corresponding db type. In SqlSever, hope you are not on Oracle? The size of varchar shouldn't be an issue, let me check...omg, it **does** matter for EFC query translator, Bummer. Sorry mate, I surrender. Go ask/open issue on their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem with strings. It is more easy to understand. See my Edit. Thanks

Comment: I also reproduced it with strings before posting the last comment. But then  found a workaround - use `= Convert.ToString(table.Field)` for such fields. Cheers.